# A question bout tenses

Tags: grammar

Is it OK if I write "the author did not have his idea clearly stated".

If yes, what kind of tenses am I using? I know "did" is in past tense and "have ... stated" is in present perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is not present perfect.  Your sentence is simple past created with auxiliary DO, with **have** being the lexical verb. This is present perfect:

> The author has not stated his idea clearly.

There is the transitive verb **state** whose basic meaning is  "to express something verbally". Here is an example in the simple past:

> The author did not state his idea clearly.

That sentence would mean that the author stated his idea vaguely or in a confusing way.

Your sentence is not as straightforward, however.

```
The author

    did not have

            his idea clearly stated.
```

In terms of subject, it's the same as my example, "the author".  But your main verb is "did not have" instead of "did not state", and instead of a simple direct object, as I have in my example, "idea", followed by an adverb, **clearly**, you have a complement in which there is a participle clause modifying "idea".

> ...  his idea clearly stated.

You have shifted the verb **state** out of the lexical verb position into a modifying position.

Your sentence is verbose and circuitous compared to the simpler version. When might such a roundabout way of stating the fact be used?

When you avoid the simple transitive in that way, it could be to focus less on the act and more on the result of the act. The past participle adds the nuance of "completion".  Your sentence looks at the finished product rather than at the act that produced it.

> The runway model had her hair oddly styled.
>
> The job applicant had his shoes nicely polished.